# php rand() array

Tags: php, arrays, random

I need to be able to pull a random value out of my array, let's assume i have array with 100 values, how can i pull randomly 5 values out of this array?

Comment: Might want to check this out if the quality of the pseudo-randomness is important: http://cod.ifies.com/2008/05/php-rand01-on-windows-openssl-rand-on.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I just found array_rand(); maybe that?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$data = range(1, 100);

$results = array_rand($data, 5);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Note that in PHP 5.2.10 and up this no longer works.  You need to add shuffle to get randomness.

Answer (score 3):

with array_rand(), produced array  will always be ordered

$results[0] < $results[1] < $results[2] < $results[3] < $results[4]

if you want it to be unordered, after array_rand(), you can use shuffle() function

```
$data = range(1, 100);
$results = array_rand($data, 5);
shuffle($result);
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

you can do:

```
<?php
 $input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
 $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
 echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
 echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

can this be done with repeating the echo or print command ( `echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";`
)

Comment: This doesn't talk about the user's own array but instead a random function